# Json response vue

Tags: javascript, json, api, vue.js

Newbie question.

I'm trying to print a city name using the props.

Having {{ props.feed.location }} print me:

```
{ "latitude": 50.85, "longitude": 4.35, "name": "Brussels, Belgium", "id": 213633143 }
```

But whenever I do {{ props.feed.location.name }} to print the city, I get JS error:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null"

found in

---> <VueInstagram>
       <Insta> at src/components/Insta.vue
         <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

code

```
  <template v-slot:feeds="props" class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <li class="fancy-list card list-unstyled">
          <div class="innerinfo row">
            <div class="col-4">
              <!--  <img v-bind:src="props.feed.images.standard_resolution.url" /> -->
              <a v-bind:href="props.feed.link">
                <img
                  class="img-fluid rounded"
                  v-bind:src="props.feed.images.standard_resolution.urlNOT"
                />
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8">
              <span class="likes row align-items-center">
                <font-awesome-icon
                  icon="heart"
                  class="mr-2"
                  :class="{ 'light-text': isDarkMode, 'dark-text': !isDarkMode }"
                />
                <h5
                  :class="{ 'light-text': isDarkMode, 'dark-text': !isDarkMode }"
                >{{ props.feed.likes.count }}</h5>
              </span>
              <span
                :class="{ 'light-text': isDarkMode, 'dark-text': !isDarkMode }"
              >{{ props.feed.location.name }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Feed response:

```
  "data": [{
        "comments": {
            "count": 0
        },
        "caption": {
            "created_time": "1296710352",
            "text": "Inside le truc #foodtruck",
            "from": {
                "username": "kevin",
                "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
                "type": "user",
                "id": "3"
            },
            "id": "26621408"
        },
        "likes": {
            "count": 15
        },
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/BWrVZ/",
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "created_time": "1296710327",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "type": "image",
        "users_in_photo": [],
        "filter": "Earlybird",
        "tags": ["foodtruck"],
        "id": "22721881",
        "location": {
            "latitude": 37.778720183610183,
            "longitude": -122.3962783813477,
            "id": "520640",
            "street_address": "",
            "name": "Le Truc"
        }
    },
    {
        "videos": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4",
                "width": 480,
                "height": 480
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640
            },
        "comments": {
            "count": 2
        },
        "caption": null,
        "likes": {
            "count": 1
        },
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/D/",
        "created_time": "1279340983",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "type": "video",
        "users_in_photo": null,
        "filter": "Vesper",
        "tags": [],
        "id": "363839373298",
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "full_name": "Kevin S",
            "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "location": null
    },
   ]
}
```

This is the basic response, so I target location > city.
As I mentioned before everything else prints okay, links, likes, etc. except the location city, but if I print location alone, works.

Comment: can you share the what `props.feed` looks like? Also the whole line where you print the prop

Comment: also, please, add some piece of your component code

Comment: @depperm it would look something like this https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/ 

check the /users/self/media/recent response

Comment: @niccord i'm not sure what to attach, i'm just printing it in a h4 tag.

Comment: @user6753358 the part of the template and some piece of code where you define the props and the data function, maybe

Comment: @niccord I am using this https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-instagram and using the usage code he has provided.

Comment: @user6753358 maybe we spot a typo, or something like that, but without some piece of code is very difficult to help you

Comment: please provide your [mcve]. you can't expect us to put together your code from other people's software and end up with the same result. It is better if you show us how you implemented these two pieces of software together

Comment: Sure, I have attached some of the code. @depperm

Comment: @niccord attached code

Comment: It's weird because it only does this with location, if I try to print something else it works okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe is async request, so when you try to show location.name on render, the location is not loaded yet.

So i think you must to add v-if, and this span will render after props.feed will loaded

```
<span v-if="props.feed.location" 
     :class="{ 'light-text': isDarkMode, 'dark-text': !isDarkMode }"
>{{ props.feed.location.name }}</span>
```

or if you need to show span even if is not loaded, you can add computed

```
<span :class="{ 'light-text': isDarkMode, 'dark-text': !isDarkMode }">locationName>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        locationName() {
            return props.feed && props.feed.location ? props.feed.location.name : "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second object of the data array, location is actually `null`

As suggested by @depperm, you can do something like:

```
{{ props.feed.location ? props.feed.location.name : '' }}
```

or, as I prefer:

```
<span v-if="props.feed && props.feed.location">
  {{ props.feed.location.name }}
</span>
```

Comment: so you could do something like: `{{props.feed.location?props.feed.location.name:''}}`